# extend internet connection

Tags: internet-connection

Currently I have a router in the house (BT HomeHub) however need to get internet to 2 other buildings on the same property.  The first is approximately 100 metres away with no easy line of sight and the other about 20 metres futher same however does have a line of sight.  Both are well out of the range of my current wireless and I have tried various (fairly cheap) aerials to increase this range with no success.

The properties each have their own mains supply and as such I can't use powerline networking, and as the house is a listed building I am limited as to what I can do to it (e.g no satellite style dishes fitted to the side of the house!).  Finally I have received a quote from more than 1 telecoms provider which is very expensive and as such not currently an option.

Does anyone have any recommendations as to the hardware / software that could be used to achieve this?

Comment: Are you prevented from trenching?

Comment: You say the properties have their own power supplies but do they share a common fuse/circuit breaker panel or are they on totally separate phases?

Comment: Following on MaQleod: Is there existing conduit connecting the two structures? Particularly the two furthest apart?

Comment: I'm not prevented from trenching however there is a fair amount of concrete in the way.  As for the power, I'm pretty sure they are all on different circuit breakers.  Is there a way to check?

Comment: You'd have to follow the property power feeds back to a common point (if any). A quick check would be 'are the properties on their own electricity meters' (ie: separate dwellings) as powerline adaptors don't work well through meters (see note). If all the buildings are just 'outbuildings' I'd be tempted to buy a pair of powerline plugs and try them. *Note: Having said that, I had a working powerline link  (only about 1-2Mbit though) between two parts of a barn conversion that was divided into two company offices with separate meters AND they were on separate phases.*

Comment: When you tried bigger wireless antennas, did you have bigger kit at both ends because don't forget that the transmission/reception is a two-way street - I have encountered installs where a large antenna has been installed at the 'main' end but the 'other' end has still been a laptop with a lowly internal wire and so the link did not work. I have managed approx 300m with a pair of 802.11g routers running dd-wrt in bridge mode using directional antennas at both ends and the power increased from 25 to 70mW. As Andrejs says - 802.11n may make it - it's a try-it-and-see moment again!

Answer (score 0):

You need an Industrial grade solution of wireless hardware, there are many, this is just one.

http://www.data-linc.com/fastlinc/

Might be best to hire a consultant to get the job done right.

Answer (score 0):

Just go buy 802.11n router (approximate outdoor range is 250m, indoor 70m, according to Wikipedia), should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

According to Wikipedia both [Cat5e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable#Maximum_cable_segment_length) and [Cat6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable#Maximum_length) Ethernet cables are specified to a maximum length of 100 meters. If you can run a conduit from your house to the nearest of the two buildings you should be able to set up a wireless [802.11n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009#Comparison) extension to your network that would cover both buildings (approximate maximum range of 70 - 250 meters, YMMV)

Edit: As mentioned by Linker3000, running cable between two buildings on different electrical circuits may be against local building codes. Check with your local authority before beginning this kind of project. Also, as mentioned by Link3000, different circuits may cause additional concerns with grounding which would require further condsideration; consult a local licensed electrician for mitigation methods. MaQleod's suggestion of a shielded cable with 25 twisted pairs (for reference Cat5/6 has 4 TP) would allow for greater data redundancy along with reduced external interference thanks to the shielding. I imagine some sort of data repeater on each end with a 4 to 24 splitter would be required, but this is unfamiliar territory for me.

Comment: The 100 meters is pretty much a straight line distance - it would be a lot further to install a cable out of sight, at least double

Comment: Running data wiring between buildings on different power circuits raises code/regulations issues due to ground potential differences which can not only disrupt signals but can also cause a shock risk so this needs to be researched properly. In many cases, such a hookup is not permitted.

Comment: This kind of distance, especially underground, would be better off with a shielded 25 pair cable, not cat5e or cat6.